# field 'info' must be a network type

Tags: tinyos, nesc

I'm a beginner and I try to create a struct in nesc for a tinyos app, but i have this error that i don't know how to fix.
Any ideas?
The code of the struct is:

```
typedef nx_struct Message
{
nx_uint16_t ID
float info;
} messaget;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing a semicolon after `ID`. Also, the name you are giving your type is very close to `message_t` which is already used by TinyOS - I would recommend giving it a more descriptive name, like `MyInformationMessage_t`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `;` after `nx_uint16_t ID`. A sample message may go like this:

```
typedef nx_struct test_message
{
    nx_uint16_t ID
    float info;
} test_message_t;
```

If you want to learn more about how to use structs to define message formats and directly access messages. You may refer to section 3.5.3 *Platform-independent types* in [TinyOS Programming](http://csl.stanford.edu/~pal/pubs/tos-programming-web.pdf)
, a Book by David Gay and Philip A. Levis.